# Unexpected token, expected {

Tags: reactjs, enums, flowtype

In my .flowconfig i've added `enums=true` under options :

```
[options]
enums=true
```

however i'm getting this error, and app created with createreactapp doesnt wanna compile this enum.

```
Unexpected token, expected "{" (2:7)

  1 | // @flow
> 2 | export enum Variant {
    |        ^
  3 |   Primary = 'primary',
  4 |   Secondary = 'secondary',
  5 |   Success = 'success',
```

I've been googling without luck, maybe someone here solved this problem ?

update:
I'm getting the same error after creating a fresh app using Create React App (2.0) for which Flow claims that  : "Create React App already supports Flow by default." as it can be seen on their page :
https://flow.org/en/docs/tools/create-react-app/

Answer (score 0):

Have you done prerequisites including these and others that are mentioned in the following links? (It seems your current setting does not support enum syntax yet)

- Upgrade your tooling (e.g. Prettier, Babel, Flow, etc.) to support
  the new syntax
- Add babel-plugin-transform-flow-enums to your Babel transform
  pipeline
- Add the flow-enums-runtime module to your production dependencies
  (called from the output of the transform)
- Enable in your .flowconfig by adding enums=true in the [options]
  section

For details refer to this this post:

[Introducing Flow Enums](https://medium.com/flow-type/introducing-flow-enums-16d4239b3180)

[Enabling enums in your project](https://flow.org/en/docs/enums/enabling-enums/)

Comment: Yes and after everything failing i created a new app using template that supports flow and it still gives same error.

Comment: @eskander Create React App already supports Flow by default. -> https://flow.org/en/docs/tools/create-react-app/